# Assign new objects in collection random number for property - VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I created a new class module that looks like this:

```
Private pNum As Double


Public Property Get Num() As Double
    Num = pNum 
End Property
Public Property Let Num(Value As Double)
    pNum = Value
End Property
```

I'm trying to add random numbers to a collection, as an object property.
This just provides me with 3 objects with the same random number.

```
Sub Add_number()
    Dim rand_num As Cnum 
    Set rand_num = New Cnum

    Dim RandColl As New Collection 

    Dim numCount As Integer
    numCount = 3


    Do
        RandColl.Add rand_num 
        rand_num.num = rnd()
    Loop Until RandColl.Count = numCount


End Sub
```

Comment: Consider adding [`Randomize`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/randomize-statement) somewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because you are adding every time the same object instance.
Write your code like this:

```
Sub Add_number()
    Dim rand_num As Cnum 
    'Set rand_num = New Cnum '<-- remove the unique initialization from here
    Dim RandColl As New Collection 

    Dim numCount As Integer
    numCount = 3
    Randomize '<-- also, add the call to the randomize module

    Do
        Set rand_num = New Cnum '<-- move it in the loop to create a new instance of Cnum each time
        RandColl.Add rand_num 
        rand_num.num = rnd()
    Loop Until RandColl.Count = numCount


End Sub
```